# JVM Crash: scavenge_contents_parallel

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

I have a JVM with 1.8TB of heap space. Starting from last night, it crashes every couple of hours on:

> [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC)
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd88e4f7233, pid=186953, tid=0x00007e14ea7b2700
>   JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64)
>
> Problematic frame:
>
> V  [libjvm.so+0x3ff233]
>   CardTableExtension::scavenge_contents_parallel(ObjectStartArray*, MutableSpace*, HeapWord*, PSPromotionManager*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0xbf3
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   [See file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L2IPaybfFeTktEdFB4eUY4ckE/view?usp=sharing)

Anyone encountered that and knows what's causing it?

Comment: "An error report file with more information is saved as:" ... post the file instead of just the error message

Comment: Added to the original question

Comment: One of the hit is JDK-8086034 which is closed as cannot reproduce. It ic GC crash, withoit reproducer it will be difficult to identify the roort cause.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything I can add that will make it clearer?

Comment: "Starting from last night, it crashes every couple of hours on" - well, did you change anything during that night?

Comment: No, but this process depends processes traffic that comes from an external source, so maybe we had some sort of a peak. I would still like to know what caused it to crash.